# Mysql Query is not Working in Php File

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, ezsql

I am using original(no-change) ezsql-mysql class in php. my database engine is innodb. everything works great but one query in one page. As I copy the code base from some other working pages everything needed like the classes and functions are already added. Just before the problem query there is another query which is working normally. Also the query with problem is working outside of php file when I directly copy paste it to the phpmyadmin.

```
    $db->query("
    BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO places (name, latitude, longitude) 
      VALUES ('Place of $event_name', '$latitude', '$longitude');
    INSERT INTO events (place_code, event_name, start_time, owner_id) 
      VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$event_name', '$start_time', '$owner_id');
    COMMIT;
    ");
//this echo part was just for copying to phpmyadmin
    echo "
    BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO places (name, latitude, longitude) 
      VALUES('Place of $event_name', '$latitude', '$longitude');
    INSERT INTO events (place_code, event_name, start_time, owner_id) 
      VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$event_name', '$start_time', '$owner_id');
    COMMIT;
    ";
```

Everytime I use that page my server generates an error log in the directory of that page. and the error is

```
    [29-Sep-2013 12:58:00] PHP Warning:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO places (name, latitude, longitude) 
  VALUES ('Place of asd', '39.76' at line 2 in /home7/eyselnet/public_html/business/injoin/demo/sql/ez_sql_mysql.php on line 233
```

And this is what happen When I just copy and paste same query in phpmyadmin

```
BEGIN;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
 INSERT INTO places (name, latitude, longitude) VALUES('Place of asd', '39.7617657', '30.5056083');# 1 row affected.
 INSERT INTO events (place_code, event_name, start_time, owner_id) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'asd', '1357884000', '1');# 1 row affected.
 COMMIT;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

Can you please help me find out what is the problem? In the worst case I can change my code to make it work in a different way. But instead of that I am asking for help to understand. because it look so strange that a query which work normally on phpmyadmin is having problem in the php file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do `begin` and `commit` as part of the same query... if you're using a transactional db engine, do them as separate queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the mentioned class, but `mysql(i)` functions in php (I guess PDO, too) only let you perform one query per function call. So you will need to separate your `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;` to own MySQL queries.

EDIT: You will of course have to do the two `INSERTs` separately, too.

Comment: yes, it is true. probably this was the problem. when I do a quick search I found that ; [mysqli_multi_query](http://se2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)
but apparently my ezsql class doesnt support that.

Comment: Please note that the restriction of one query per call is also a security mechanism to prevent some types of SQL Injections. Don't use `mysql[i]_multi_query()` unless you really need to (and I can't really think of a case like that).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just thought it is better to use less connections, less queries to optimize things.